# Font not rendering in Firefox, but renders appropriately on all other browsers

Tags: firefox, font-face, webfonts

I am using a .ttf font within my page and importing it with

```
@font-face
{
  font-family:myFont;
  src:url(/fonts/myfont.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

then I use it on certain elements

```
p,span
{
  font-family:ubuntu;
}
```

The font works great on all browsers (even IE) except for Firefox. the strange thing was that it worked with problems (clipped / broken) until I updated.

These are the errors that appear on the 'css' section of the console

```
downloadable font: GPOS: glyph id 4144 too high >= 253

downloadable font: GPOS: Failed to parse pair set table 26

downloadable font: GPOS: Failed to parse pair pos format 1 

downloadable font: Layout: Failed to parse lookup subtable 1

downloadable font: Layout: Failed to parse subtable 0 

downloadable font: Layout: Failed to parse lookup 1 

downloadable font: GPOS: Failed to parse lookup list table 

downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer
```